# R formula with a matrix on the left (instead of a response term)

Tags: r, formula

I'm reading the doc of `lme4` and came across this code:

```
gm1 <- glmer(cbind(incidence, size - incidence) ~ period + (1 |herd), cbpp, binomial)
```

I've never seen a matrix being on the left of the `~` in a formula before. The doc on R's formula also doesn't mention this case.

What does it mean? What's being used as the response variable? Checking `gm1@frame` shows that both variables in the matrix on the left shows up in the model frame.

Comment: First line of the examples of `?glmer`: `## generalized linear mixed model`

Comment: I saw the code from the docs of `glmer` -- my question is what does the code mean, and is there an application outside of `lme4` and in general R?